# How to ensure file integrity in Google Cloud Firebase Storage?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I am writing a web service where users can upload and download files to their user directory in Google Cloud Firebase Storage.

Imagine a user uploads a 1GB file to the storage. While the user uploads the file, it is already visible by other "processes".

What are common techniques to identify a file being uploaded 100% from a process that does not have the upload stats?

One approach in a local environment would be to call the file first "my-file.iso.tmp" and later rename them by removing the suffix, since a rename operation is atomic. But that doesn't seem to be a suitable solution for my Firebase Storage problem.

Any insights are highly appreciated!

Comment: What are the other processes?

Comment: E.g. other browser windows listing all the users files

Comment: When the user starts uploading the file you could set a value (0) in realtime database which can alert other devices about the upload and when the upload is complete you can update the same value to 1 to notify other devices that the upload is completed. To make it more fancy, you could continuously update the upload % in the database. Also I don't think you can rename a file.

Comment: Seems like there is no builtin solution! I will check out realtime databases. If noone else has an alternative I would accept this as an answer

Comment: Sure, I'll post the realtime db way as one.

Comment: It's not very clear to me what is the problem you're trying to prevent.  Please clarify by editing the question to post a realistic scenario where you have observe the issue.

Comment: *File integrity* doesn't seem to be correct phrase to track upload status maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any method to rename a file in Firebase storage. If you want to show realtime upload stats across all user's devices then using realtime database could be a way.

```js
var uploadTask = storageRef.child('images/rivers.jpg').put(file);

uploadTask.on('state_changed', 
  async (snapshot) => {
    var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
    console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
    await updateUploadStatus(progress)
    }
  }, 
  (error) => {
    // Handle unsuccessful uploads
  }, 
  () => {
    // Upload completed
    await uploadStatus(100)
    uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((downloadURL) => {
      console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
    });
  }
);

async function updateUploadStatus(progress) {
  const dbRef = firebase.database().ref(`users/${userID}/${fileID}`)
  await dbRef.update(progress)
}
```

The `updateUploadStatus` will update progress to realtime database and you can listen it on all other devices where user has logged in (and is active) as follows:

```js
var fileRef = firebase.database().ref(`users/${userID}/${fileID}`);
fileRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
  const data = snapshot.val();
  updateFileProgress(data);
});
```

It's upto you how you get that `fileID` on other devices or you could listen to `users/${userID}` node itself. While the progress is not 100 percent you can grey out that file icon or something like that.